# Some issues with DockerFile

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hello I have a problem with setting up a dockerFile. I want to say that I am new under docker.
here is the docker version

```
C:\>docker version
Client:
Version:      18.03.1-ce
API version:  1.37
Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:12:48 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm`


Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:21:42 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

I created a docker image in which I copied an executable. I manage to run the .exe in a container by starting it
. Currently I would like to automate things using a dockerFile. My image is called `bt1: version1` it is based on microsoft / windowsservercore.

Here is my dockerFile in question.

The goal is to start a container then inside to modify the file test.xml then to launch the application BT_simulator.exe.

```
FROM bt1:version1
WORKDIR "/BTsimulatorV1.1/release"
RUN powershell.exe
RUN "$doc = [xml](Get-Content /BTsimulatorV1.1/release/test.xml) 
&& $doc.parameters.connection.port = " " 
&& $doc.parameters.connection.ipAddress = " " 
&& $doc.parameters.Tool_EEPROM.Serial_Number = " " 
&& $doc.save("/BTsimulatorV1.1/release/test.xml") 
&& BT_simulator.exe
```

I do not have to achieve the expected behavior. Can you help me please?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Also I would make the port and ip static and use docker to map a port to the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manipulation of the xml file should not be done in the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile runs only once, during image build. 
What you need is an ENTRYPOINT script which will do the file manipulation and start the exe.

Everything from RUN powershell.exe onwards should be deleted. The script should be put into an .ps script and ADDed to the image. Then call it with ENTRYPOINT.